# How to update bmp files in a zip archive in node.js

Tags: node.js, bmp

I am writing a nodejs script which should do the following:

```
Replace 10 or more bmp files within the zip
```

Because the zip file is large, I would like to replace the files without unzipping and rezipping the file.

Is that possible?

Comment: I found at least one [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) that claim it can do so, you could analyse how they did it and see if it is still working.

Comment: In that module, the file content is needed to update a file. There is a method readAsText, but I don`t think that will work for bmp files... and I don`t know if there is any other module to get the bmp file`s content...

Comment: Extract only the file you need so you have the content, update it, and replace it? Don't know if it will work with binary data either, but worth the try.

Comment: Else you ll need to find another process altogether to update your archive, like preparing the archive in advance, modifying the architecture so that you can send the images separately from the first archive